# Convert genotypes format '12' to ACTG format

Tags: r, dplyr

**Hello,**

**Please I need help to convert my '12' genotype format to ACGT format based on snp_info file.**

**Example from df (row 1)**

```
sample1 1/2 1/2 2/1 2/1
```

The first SNP of sample1 is heterozygous (1/2). 1 is ref allele (A) and 2 is alt allele (G) (see snp_info).

I would like to automate the process to convert all genotypes in my real data (900 samples / 30 genotypes).

```
# df
df = t(data.frame( 
sample1 =c('1/2','1/2','2/1','2/1'), 
sample2 =c('2/1','1/1','1/2','2/1'), 
sample3 =c('2/1','2/1','1/1','1/2'), 
sample4 =c('1/1','2/2','2/2','2/2')))

# snp_info

snp_info = data.frame(
snp =c('11_524568','12_542656','12_558659','13_8457658'), 
position =c('524568','542656','558659','8457658'), 
ref =c('A','T','T','G'), 
alt=c('G','C','C','A'))
```

Desired output

```
desired_output = t(data.frame(
sample1 =c('A/G','T/C','C/T','A/G'), 
sample2 =c('G/A','T/T','T/C','A/G'), 
sample3 =c('G/A','C/T','T/T','G/A'), 
sample4 =c('A/A','C/T','C/C','A/A')
))
```

I tried for loop for the first SNP but I didnt get the desired output

```
desired_output = t(data.frame(
sample1 =c('','','',''), 
sample2 =c('','','',''), 
sample3 =c('','','',''), 
sample4 =c('','','','')))
tp = as.data.frame(tp)

geno = list()
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    geno[i] = paste(snp_info[i,3],'/',file_info[i,4])
    desired_output[i,1] = geno[i]
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-elegant solution:

```
# EXAMPLE
df <- t(data.frame( 
  sample1 =c('1/2','1/2','2/1','2/1'), 
  sample2 =c('2/1','1/1','1/2','2/1'), 
  sample3 =c('2/1','2/1','1/1','1/2'), 
  sample4 =c('1/1','2/2','2/2','2/2')))

snp_info = data.frame(
  snp =c('11_524568','12_542656','12_558659','13_8457658'), 
  position =c('524568','542656','558659','8457658'), 
  ref =c('A','T','T','G'), 
  alt=c('G','C','C','A'))

desired_output = t(data.frame(
  sample1 =c('','','',''), 
  sample2 =c('','','',''), 
  sample3 =c('','','',''), 
  sample4 =c('','','','')))

for (i in 1L:ncol(df)) {
  desired_output[,i] <- gsub("1", snp_info[i,3L], df[,i])
  desired_output[,i] <- gsub("2", snp_info[i,4L], desired_output[,i])
}
```

However, speed does not seem to play a major role for your amount data.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @tacoman is quite acceptable.
I would improve it a bit:

```r
df <- t(data.frame(
  sample1 = c('1/2', '1/2', '2/1', '2/1'),
  sample2 = c('2/1', '1/1', '1/2', '2/1'),
  sample3 = c('2/1', '2/1', '1/1', '1/2'),
  sample4 = c('1/1', '2/2', '2/2', '2/2')
))

snp_info = data.frame(
  snp = c('11_524568', '12_542656', '12_558659', '13_8457658'),
  position = c('524568', '542656', '558659', '8457658'),
  ref = c('A', 'T', 'T', 'G'),
  alt = c('G', 'C', 'C', 'A')
)


stopifnot(ncol(df) == ncol(snp_info))
output <- matrix(rep("", ncol(df)*nrow(df)), ncol = ncol(df))
rownames(output) <- paste0("sample", 1:nrow(df))

for (i in 1L:ncol(df)) {
  output[, i] <- gsub("1", snp_info$ref[i], df[, i])
  output[, i] <- gsub("2", snp_info$alt[i], output[, i])
}
output
#>         [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
#> sample1 "A/G" "T/C" "C/T" "A/G"
#> sample2 "G/A" "T/T" "T/C" "A/G"
#> sample3 "G/A" "C/T" "T/T" "G/A"
#> sample4 "A/A" "C/C" "C/C" "A/A"
```